# Trigger job in post build step(not post-build-action)on condition-step: current-status not able to trigger job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

- job:
  name: 'maven_job'
  project-type: maven
  description: "Modified job"
  concurrent: false
  scm:

  - git:
      url: https://github.com/ranjitkumar518/myfirstrepo.git
      branches:
        - '${branch}'
    maven:
    maven-name: maven-3.2.1
    root-pom: pom.xml
    goals: clean package

    ## post build step for conditional shell and trigger a job using this script with block: true

  builders:

  - conditional-step:
         condition-kind: current-status
         condition-worst: SUCCESS
         condition-best: SUCCESS
         on-evaluation-failure: fail
         steps:
            - shell: "ls -la /etc"
            - trigger-builds:
               - project: test_job

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood what you need... see if this can help:

Maybe not to elegant, but it works!

1: Catch all the build result you want to catch (in this case SUCCESS).

2: Inject an env variable valued with the job status

[image: Step 1]

3: Do the Same for any kind of other status (in this case I catch from abort to unstable)

[image]

4: After you'll be able to use the value for whatever you wanna do.. in this case I'm passing it to an ANT script! (Or you can directly load it from ANT as Environment variable...)

[image]

Hope it can help!